# print from sql database as its showns in table

Tags: php, html, mysql, printing, formatting

I've a long text in my database, with spaces and rows.
I query it and print it like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $replyby = $row['username'];
    $inlagg = $row['comment'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    print "<tr><td>$replyby</td><td>$inlagg</td><td>$date</td></tr>";
}
```

as you see its inside a table, but the text inside `$inlagg` is long with spaces and rows, how can I, or how should I, or is it possible print it with spaces and rows? Formatted as it's formatted in my database.

Comment: Have you tried `$inlagg = nl2br( $row['comment'] )`? At least all newline characters will be substituted with `<br/>` tags. See [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $replyby = $row['username'];
    $inlagg = $row['comment'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    print "<tr><td>$replyby</td><td>$inlagg</td><td>$date</td></tr>";
}
```

Change your code like so:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $replyby = $row['username'];
    $inlagg = nl2br($row['comment']);
    $date = $row['date'];
    print "<tr><td>".$replyby."</td><td>".$inlagg."</td><td>".$date."</td></tr>";
}
```

I have used  Concatenation when `print`ing the variables. This is entirely optional, but the main function: `nl2br`  will replace all new line breaks with the HTML `<br>`

So whether your table has a `\r\n` or just `\n` it will convert it to a HTML line break

Comment: @user2429917 If this solved your problem press the arrow under the reputation arrows to mark this as the answer